# Changing the contents of localhost:8080

Tags: json, node.js, web-development-server

I want to be able to visit localhost:8080 on my browser and have it automatically redirect or even be the place of my html file home.html.

So instead of having to visit localhost:8080/home.html, I can just visit localhost:8080 and view the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Rename `home.html` to `index.html`